# How do I use `[` correctly with (l|s)apply to select a specific column from a list of matrices?

Tags: r

Consider the following situation where I have a list of n matrices (this is just dummy data in the example below) in the object `myList`

```
mat <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 3)
myList <- list(mat1 = mat, mat2 = mat, mat3 = mat, mat4 = mat)
```

I want to select a specific column from each of the matrices and do something with it. This will get me the first column of each matrix and return it as a matrix (`lapply()` would give me a list either is fine).

```
sapply(myList, function(x) x[, 1])
```

What I can't seem able to do is use `[` directly as a function in my `sapply()` or `lapply()` incantations. `?'['` tells me that I need to supply argument `j` as the column identifier. So what am I doing wrong that this does't work?

```
> lapply(myList, `[`, j = 1)
$mat1
[1] 1

$mat2
[1] 1

$mat3
[1] 1

$mat4
[1] 1
```

Where I would expect this:

```
$mat1
[1] 1 2 3 4

$mat2
[1] 1 2 3 4

$mat3
[1] 1 2 3 4

$mat4
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I suspect I am getting the wrong `[` method but I can't work out why? Thoughts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are getting the 1 argument form of `[`. If you do `` lapply(myList, `[`, i =, j = 1) `` it works.

Comment: Took a while to figure out how to escape backticks inside inline code.  Use <code>&#96;foo&#96;</code>.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/escaping-backticks-fails

Comment: @user275455 - I thought I'd tried that version. Still doesn't answer the real underlying Q of why supplying only `j` doesn't work. But thanks for that.

Comment: @Ritchie - thanks for that. Struggled and give up with it when composing my question, hence the `?'['` :-)

Comment: @user275455 As I note in my own answer below, the argument names are ignored, and it is the positional matching that is important, and that is why your answer works. Thanks for the insight. Accepted.

Comment: @Shane - your solution (without quotes around `[`) does not work for me somehow

Comment: @Shane - sorry, I thought your comment on `Oct 29 '10 at 17:02` above was an alternate solution made up by you.

Comment: @daroczig Ooops...didn't notice that.  I guess so!

Answer (score 15):

After two pints of Britain's finest ale and a bit of cogitation, I realise that this version will work:

```
lapply(myList, `[`, , 1)
```

i.e. don't name anything and treat it like I had done `mat[ ,1]`. Still don't grep why naming `j` doesn't work...

...actually, having read `?'['` more closely, I notice the following section:

```
Argument matching:

     Note that these operations do not match their index arguments in
     the standard way: argument names are ignored and positional
     matching only is used.  So ‘m[j=2,i=1]’ is equivalent to ‘m[2,1]’
     and *not* to ‘m[1,2]’.
```

And that explains my quandary above. Yeah for actually reading the documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason is that `[` is a primitive method and so ignores argument names.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `[` is a `.Primitive` function.  It has no `j` argument.  And there is no `[.matrix` method.

```
> `[`
.Primitive("[")
> args(`[`)
NULL
> methods(`[`)
 [1] [.acf*            [.AsIs            [.bibentry*       [.data.frame     
 [5] [.Date            [.difftime        [.factor          [.formula*       
 [9] [.getAnywhere*    [.hexmode         [.listof          [.noquote        
[13] [.numeric_version [.octmode         [.person*         [.POSIXct        
[17] [.POSIXlt         [.raster*         [.roman*          [.SavedPlots*    
[21] [.simple.list     [.terms*          [.ts*             [.tskernel*
```

Though this really just begs the question of how `[` is being dispatched on matrix objects...